# Creating Custom Hook for my plugin

Tags: plugins, hooks

In my plugin I have in admin menu function Media Organizations List. Here I get a list of all Organizations. There are 3 organizations types

- affiliate
- direct
- bureau

The total list will get long. Therefor I need a custom hook to filter the 3 organization types to get a better view.

I have read several documents but not understand exact what to do.

Is there someone of you who can help me making this custom hook? It would be very helpful.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/creating-custom-hooks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, register the filter hooks with the handy [`apply_filters`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) tool:

```
function wpse_238394_org_types() {
    return apply_filters(
        "my_org_types",
        array( "affiliate", "direct", "bureau" )
    );
}
```

Now, `wpse_238394_org_types()` will return the default 3 types being not filtered yet, so we one more custom type:

```
add_filter("my_org_types", function($types) { 
    $types[] = "custom_type";
    return $types;
});
```

Now if you debug `wpse_238394_org_types()` it should be including the `custom_type` item along the defaults.

Hope that helps. Please also take a look at the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/creating-custom-hooks/ as jdm2112 suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Have add function wpse_238394_org_types() { into class List_Table_banner_affiliates extends WP_List_Table {
But where to save add_filter("my_org_types", function($types) {  ??

Comment: `add_filter` part can be used in a plugin, or in the child theme's functions file.. Just anywhere in your plugin e.g in the class `init` method.

Comment: add_filter part is added in my plugin. How do I get to see these filter options on my my-plugin/includes/affliates.php file?

Comment: Whenever you call for the types use the function `wpse_238394_org_types()`.. `var_dump( wpse_238394_org_types() )`

Comment: I've got array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "affiliate" [1]=> string(6) "direct" [2]=> string(6) "bureau" [3]=> string(11) "custom_type" } ;
Thats a start. But how to get this as filter at the top of the listing including that they indeed filter the listing as needed. Sorry but I am not familiar with this at all. And the docs do not give me a good help at all.